Was Christianity the first intentionally multicultural religion?
The earliest Christian writings, notably the writings of Paul in his letters and of Luke in the Acts of the Apostles, address issues of multiculturalism in the relationships, beliefs, and practices of Jews and Gentiles. Based upon extra-Biblical sources and the histories of other religions, what evidence is there to support (or refute) a claim that Christianity was the first intentionally multicultural religion?

I feel like this may be better in history SE. You are asking for extra biblical sources, to support/refute the claim. This is not inherently about Christianity

I’m voting to close this question because its not about Christianity but History

@depperm I intentionally chose the audience of Christianity Stack Exchange for this question because of the collective knowledge of Christianity and the potential knowledge of Christianity in the context of history. I did not choose History SE because it would be a broader and less focused knowledge base. I disagree with your assessment that this question is not about Christianity, but we can agree to disagree.

@depperm There is the apocrypha as well as the writings of multiple church fathers and saints. These would all be "extra-Biblical" sources. So saying the question is seeking "non-canon texts" is not a valid reason IMHO. I can't vote though.

part of it is the broadness. There are hundreds+ of religions, lose meaning of multicultural, thousands of years, and then the request to support OR refute the claim. It's so open ended. It doesn't ask for a Christian perspective so I feel like it'd be better in history. my opinion

@depperm I think using just the Bible it was possible to answer, with some basic history of religion knowledge thrown in. :) But I understand your point too.

Essence of Christianity Any answer must first research the "essence" of  generally-accepted Christian teaching, and show the "intentionality of multiculturalism" in its doctrines in the first century.  And then compare it with other religions. This being so, this question is on-topic here in C.SE.

Not sure whether this is what you're looking for (it would help for you to clarify your question) but here it is.

Before answering, I try to clarify what "multicultural religion" and what "intentional" mean:

If it simply means "everyone regardless of culture can be an adherent", then any of the world religions today qualifies: Christianity, Islam, Buddhism, Hinduism, even Judaism.

If "intentional" means active proselyting of people of other cultures even when the religion originated from an ethnic / cultural group, then Christianity certainly is (which originated from the religion of the Jews).
But so does Buddhism as it traveled from India to China and then to Japan and Korea.  As far as I know, Judaism and Hinduism are a lot less intentional in proselyting; they would welcome inquirers and after a process of initiation they would accept people from other ethnicity / culture / race into their religion.

If "multicultural" means not prioritizing a language for the sacred texts and for its rituals and liturgies, then Christianity certainly qualifies, and so do possibly Buddhism and Judaism.
Islam requires reciting the Qur'an in Arabic.  Hinduism uses Sanskrit for most of their rituals.

If "intentional" means the shedding any ethnic / cultural elements from its central doctrines and practices, then Christianity certainly is, because it discarded the ceremonial and civic laws of Judaism or transformed them into universal laws that are blind to ethnicity and culture.  Even circumcision and kosher eating were eliminated.
But Buddhism from the start was also universal because its central teachings are humanistic, so it intentionally eliminated cultural aspects of Hinduism.

If "intentionally multicultural" means giving its adherents equal standing before God then yes, Christianity from the start is so, cf Paul in several of his letters (Romans 9-11 and Ephesians 2:11-22) admonishing the two ethnicities (Jews and Gentiles) not to have superiority over each other, also implicit in Paul teaching equality among adherents between slave & slaveowners (Philemon), rich and poor participate in the Lord's Supper (1 Corinthian 11:17-26), the prohibition for Gentile Christians to adopt specifically Jewish customs (Gal 2:14), and the imperative for cultural inclusion (Paul rebuking Peter in Gal 2:11-13 because who you eat with at the time was highly significant).
I don't think Hinduism qualifies here, because of the caste system, nor does Judaism which has separate rules between Jews and Gentiles (the Noahic laws).  But Buddhism is certainly egalitarian, so "equal standing before God", or should I say "equal standing before Buddha" (because they don't factor God into their teachings).

If "intentionally multicultural" means transforming EVERY culture it comes into contact with, without requiring one to abandon any compatible cultural attributes then Christianity certainly qualifies. From the beginning Christianity was involved "politically" by wanting to eliminate injustice and violations of human rights in the host society to uphold the ethic of Jesus to protect and to affirm the inherent human value of the marginalized.  It was famous for saving the abandoned female babies and taking care of the poor in the first centuries.
Judaism is similarly transformative, their adherents DO practice blessing their host country, a practice since the Babylonian Exile (Jer 29:7).  But Buddhism advocates a retreat from the world into the culture of monasticism.  Hinduism seems to be a mixed bag; one group is similar to Buddhism but other groups do thrive in any culture.  At any rate, I don't see much attempt by Hinduism to transform a culture; instead they try to stand above culture by focusing only on the spiritual aspect of an individual.

If "intentionally multicultural" means not prioritizing a locale in the practice of the religion, then Christianity certainly qualifies too.
Judaism and Buddhism qualify too.  Islam doesn't qualify, since one of the five pillars is to do Hajj, once in a lifetime duty to do pilgrimage to Mecca.  Similarly, some groups of Hinduism don't qualify as they teach pilgrimage to holy sites in India as a way to obtain spiritual merit.

If "intentionally multicultural" means full acceptance of mixed-race, mixed-culture, and mixed-ethnic marriages, then Christianity certainly qualifies.  There is explicitly no degradation (religion-wise) for those couples as long as they are both "equally yoked" with Christ.
Islam qualifies too.  But I don't think Judaism qualifies here, since matrilineal Jewishness is critical to the descendant's Jewish identity.  Caste-conscious Hinduism adherents would not allow mixed marriage.  Buddhism looks down on marriage as a whole as interfering with the highest spiritual aspiration.


If one seeks an answer that includes ALL the above meanings, I would say Christianity is the MOST intentionally multicultural religion since from the early church until today it consistently teaches that:

Anyone can be an adherent
We intentionally proselytize to people of any culture (the Great Commission)
We prioritize Bible translations as the first step of mission.  There is no inherent value in using a particular language for our sacred texts and for our rituals.
There is no specific ethnic / cultural elements from central practices and doctrines
Everyone has equal standing before God regardless of race, ethnicity, and culture
A Christian works for the transformation of the culture one is in while being PART of it
There is no necessary sacred place (you don't need to travel)
No "second citizen" status for mixed marriages and their descendants; no higher value attributed to non-mixed marriage for religious reason

As for being the FIRST, Buddhism was earlier than Christianity, but it fails measure #6 and #8 because it retreats FROM the culture one is born in TO its own culture of monasticism, and eventually from any sense of IDENTITY since the primary religious drive is one of nihilism.  From this perspective it is "multicultural" in name only since it goes into "no culture".
There may be an earlier "multicultural" religion fulfilling all 8 measures but already extinct and didn't have the opportunity to interact with most cultures of the world today.  So in a practical sense, Christianity can still be the FIRST.

Fair enough and well balanced+1.

Yes, but what about the religions before Christianity? I don't disagree with you. Christianity is the best religion since it started to exist. :) But it wasn't the first one to "accept all peoples" or "have equal standings of people within the religion"

@Wyrsa That's why I added the final paragraph about "extinct" religion or about a religion that doesn't have the opportunity to interact with other cultures.  If you can suggest the name of an earlier religion that I should cover, I'll read about it and update my answer.  But most importantly, the question as it stands right now IS ambiguous and probably I should VTC it as "requiring more detail".

@GratefulDisciple The worship of Marduk (AKA Baal/Bel) is the only one that comes to mind.

This is an excellent answer, but I've got a couple nitpicks: I don't think Judaism can qualify on point 7, since they emphasize the particular location of the promised land and especially the temple mount. This emphasis was stronger before 70 AD. Second, "equal standing before Buddha" doesn't really make sense as a description of Buddhism's form of egalitarianism; in most forms of Buddhism there is no personal judge, it's just impersonal Karma.

@GratefulDisciple It might be worth discussing Zoroastrianism and Pythagoreanism as some other pre-Christian religions.

@GratefulDisciple Thank you for a thorough, well-balanced, informative, and insightful answer. I was initially thinking of multicultural primarily in the context of your #2, 4, 5, and 6 in terms of incorporation (e.g., into the community of adherents) and context over mere adherence. Thank you.

Judeo-Christian Since Christianity was brought to mankind by the schoolmaster of Judaism, we must consider the original prophetic word by God to Abraham that, in thy Seed the whole world would be blessed as a candidate for consideration re being first. Eh? Peace

@raygrant I differentiate between what Judaism should have been (from the lens of Christianity) from the actual practice down to today, so I agree that if Israelites were more faithful to the Abrahamic covenant, they could have been the first.  But still, they would fail criteria #5 where even today they seem to do theodicy based on how God intended the whole "nation" of Israel ("nation" not as modern political entity) to suffer more as a kind of "light" to the brutality of nations, citing Isa 53. Unlike in Christianity where every Christian suffers more for Christ to be the light.

Honestly, there is a very easy proof here.
All of the false gods within the old testament are basically "anyone can join" as they would accept the Israelites worshiping their gods. (See all the repeated times in the old testament were God punishes israel for worshiping those idols)

"Did you offer Me sacrifices and offerings
In the wilderness forty years, O house of Israel?
You also carried Sikkuth your king
And Chiun, your idols,
The star of your gods,
Which you made for yourselves. (Amos 5:25-26)


For it was so, when Solomon was old, that his wives turned his heart after other gods; and his heart was not loyal to the LORD his God, as was the heart of his father David. For Solomon went after Ashtoreth the goddess of the Sidonians, and after Milcom the abomination of the Ammonites.


He made shrines on the high places, and made priests from every class of people, who were not of the sons of Levi. (1 Kings 12:31)



Anyone can be an adherent
They clearly spread their worship, as it flourished around Israel.
It was in whatever language the people who worshiped understood. (It wasn't like today, there were more languages then we have now)
There is no specific ethnic / cultural elements from central practices and doctrines. (This varied, but again see Marduk)
Everyone has equal standing before God regardless of race, ethnicity, and culture. (See Marduk where the king and slave were held accountable, The Jews of course did not have this)
No "second citizen" status for mixed marriages and their descendants; no higher value attributed to non-mixed marriage for religious reason. (Other then the historical tribalism, The ancient egyptian religion does not have this, the Jews did not have this)

The above list is shamelessly copied from the other answer

So no, Christianity was not the first "All are welcome" religion. It was however the first "Love thy Enemies" religion. It is definitely the most intellectually accepting on purpose religion, but not the first one.

“You have heard that it was said, ‘You shall love your neighbor and hate your enemy.’ But I say to you, love your enemies, bless those who curse you, do good to those who hate you, and pray for those who spitefully use you and persecute you, that you may be sons of your Father in heaven; for He makes His sun rise on the evil and on the good, and sends rain on the just and on the unjust. For if you love those who love you, what reward have you? Do not even the tax collectors do the same? And if you greet your brethren only, what do you do more than others? Do not even the tax collectors do so? Therefore you shall be perfect, just as your Father in heaven is perfect. (Matthew 5:43-48)


"The above list is shamelessly copied from the other answer"  Haha.  Thanks for the credit.  BTW, "Love thy enemies" doesn't have inherent cultural meaning, so I don't think that's relevant for this question, or you need to do more work to show how it is "multicultural" rather than humanistic (like Buddhism, who CERTAINLY also teaches love your enemies).

@GratefulDisciple I wasn't claiming that Loving enemies was a cultural thing. I was just saying that Christianity's big "we did it first" aspect was "loving enemies" and not "we accept all people"
